# Simplenews theming, change header image

Tags: theming, emails

I have been puzzling for weeks now and still cant find how to change a newsletters layout in simplenews in D7. 
Must say I inherited the website and, as the owner wants to create a blog and send these updates, i was looking for a solution. 
At the moment i created 2 newsletter categories: blog and newsletter.

Mail System settings are:

  Site-wide default MailSystemInterface=>defaultmailsystem

  HTML Mail module class: HTMLMailSystem

  Mime Mail module class: HTMLMailSystem

  Maillog / Mail Developer module class:HTMLMailSystem

  Simplenews module class: HTMLMailSystem

  Theme to render the emails: =>custom theme

under /admin/config/system/htmlmail the custom theme as also been enabled.

All code is in page.tpl.php and when I change something there it has effect on everything.
I can send out mails with the current setup but I do not know how to theme according to the different newsletters.

I'd like to change only 1 image in the whole system but still cant find how to do this. At this moment this image is set as a fixed path in the page.tpl.php file. I tried to create a block and use it as header, but it always remains that same image when sent.

I've also tried to:

  create page--blog.tpl.php and a page--blog--blogpost.tpl.php yet without any result.

  created an htmlmail--simplenews--[23].tpl.php file...without results.

What is it that I cannot see? Can anybody hand me a solution?
Thank you in advance